# Fixing Java.Swing absolute layout misposition

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I'm currently using `setLayout(null);` (my preference) but as usual, it's easy to run into positioning problems. In this case I've got a `AWT.Chooser` and 2 `JButton`'s. Like so, [Good One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDngx.png) Every so often upon launch the 2nd `JButton` "Cancel" will render the buttons `Y` position `+` it's `height`, Like so, [Bad One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxObU.png)
From what I could find throughout Oracles tutorials and here on Stack, it's `setLayout(null)` that's causing this issue. To fix it I've gone through various different layouts trying to find which one fits this particular design. One I found was `CardLayout` which seems to be the closest. Although getting the buttons to be in the right position doesn't fit my design.
Is there a way to fix this without using a layout manager? Am I taking the wrong approach to this? I'm not picky, changing the window size if needed is doable and if a new design is needed, that's also not a problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful mixing AWT and Swing components, they have a tendency not to always play nice together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One I found was `CardLayout` which seems to be the closest.

CardLayout? That makes no sense as that is not a layout for component positioning but rather component swapping. Are you sure you don't mean another? Myself, I usually *nest* JPanels, each with its own layout manager, and this way easily create complex GUI's that are easy to maintain.

[image]

For your GUI, I'd give the overall GUI a BorderLayout and add the central JPanel to the BorderLayout.CENTER position. I'd create a JPanel that uses `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING)` as its layout for the bottom, and add my JButtons to it, and that add that to the main JPanel in the BorderLayout.PAGE_END position. The possibilities of how to solve this are endless.